Moving both on horizontal and vertical axis
im very new to unity and programming, so this might be a really dumb question
Im trying to make my player move through the map both horizontally and vertically, but my code is not working that way. When i press the up and down keys the player also moves horizontally. What should i change ?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D _rb;

    float _walkSpeed;
    float _inputHorizontal;
    float _inputVertical;
    float _walkSpeedVertical;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        _walkSpeed = 5.5f;
        _walkSpeedVertical = 6.5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        _inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    
        if (_inputHorizontal != 0)
        {
            _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputHorizontal * _walkSpeed, 0f));
        }
        
        _inputVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (_inputVertical != 0) 
        {
            _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputVertical * _walkSpeedVertical, 0f));
        }
        if (_inputVertical + _inputHorizontal == 0)
        {
            _rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}


_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputVertical * _walkSpeedVertical, 0f)); uses _inputVertical to add a force along the x axis. Surely you mean to add it along the y axis: _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, _inputVertical * _walkSpeedVertical));. But there are better ways of doing this which avoid moving diagonally being faster than moving orthogonally.

There are quite some issues in your code. First of all, if you are applying forces you should do it in the FixedUpdate and not in Update. secondly, your
_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputVertical * _walkSpeedVertical, 0f)); 

for the vertical axis is incorrectly written, as you are assigning a Vector2 with values only in the X axis. That's why your player always moves horizontally.
void FixedUpdate()
{
    _inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    _inputVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(_inputHorizontal * _walkSpeed, _inputVertical * _walkSpeedVertical);
    
    if (_inputHorizontal != 0 || _inputVertical != 0)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(movement);
    }
    else
    {
        _rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}

By Changing it to this, you define your movement based on the horizontal and vertical input, making a direction vector. You might want to addForce it multiplying it by some speed value and Time.deltaTime,  for frame rate independance. Hope it helps.
